# how to store image in local iphone bundel

Tags: iphone, uiimage

i have one application in that i download all data in local .

in this data also image coming i want to store this image in local .

can i store this image in local?
if yes !
how ?

from online image path (url) coming.

Comment: after download this image i want to store this image in local data base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the image in UIImage and then save it to local like this;

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png"];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
```

Comment: yes this store image in local bundle. this problem solved but one new problem how can i get this image back ?